# Telerik ASP.NET MVC Grid Editing

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I want to apply editing (popup or inline) to my Grid, but it doesn't work the way I want to do it. In the documentation they use `.DataSource()`to fill the grid. My grid is filled using a DataTable: `Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.dataTableContent)`

Is there a solution to apply editing without using `.DataSource()` to fill the grid?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Try `Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.dataTableContent).DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().ServerOperation(false))`

Comment: I get a "NotSupportedException". "There is no DataSource Model Id property specified)

Comment: Add the model portion and identity your key: `Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.dataTableContent).DataSource(dataSou‌​rce => dataSource.Ajax().ServerOperation(false).Model(model => model.Id(p => p.MyModelId)))`

Comment: The problem is that the content of the Datatable differs. There are never the same columns in it. So how can I do this?

Comment: OK, big difference. Look for solutions that mention kendo grid dynamic columns such as [this one](http://blog.codebeastie.com/kendo-grid-dynamic-columns/)